# How to rename a column that is an index?

Tags: sql, db2

I want to rename a table column but it is an index therefore I get an error. How do I solve this problem?

```
ALTER TABLE <name> RENAME column <id> TO <newid>;
```

`Error: SQL0478N  DROP, ALTER, TRANSFER OWNERSHIP...`

Comment: Please show your code and the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

```
drop index
alter table
create index
```

Answer (score 2):

At the shell command line, you can use `db2 "? SQL0478N" | more`  to see the details of the error and some suggestions.

The error is telling you that the object you want to change has dependent objects, so until you handle the dependencies you cannot complete the alter action.

You can choose between doing the dependency management manually, or use a stored procedure to do it for you.

If you want to do it manually, you have to find the dependent objects, drop them, rename the column(s) , then recreate the dependencies. There can be other dependent objects, not only an index, such as packages.  If your Db2-server runs on Linux/Unix/Windows, you can use the stored procedure [DBMS_UTILITY.GET_DEPENDENCY](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.sqlpl.doc/doc/r0055165.html) , or you can query the catalog manually. It depends what is easier for you.

Recreating dependencies can be invasive, and if there are static-SQL objects that reference the relevant indexes then they will need to be rebound. For production use this can involve a service outage, which you want to avoid.

So you must be *certain* that the renaming of the column is essential. Sometimes you can just create a view with the relevant column renamed in the View but the base table remaining unchanged.

If you want try automation, and if your Db2-server runs on Linux/Unix/Windows then you can use the stored procedure [SYSPROC.ALTOBJ](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0011934.html) - there is a learning curve however and this is not suitable for all schema-evolutions.